# Convert coordinates to Google Maps link

Tags: javascript, regex, hyperlink, gps, coordinates

What I'd like to do is to create a userscript to convert different GPS coordinates to a hyperlink taking to Google Maps.

**Example**:

I have a page with `24.197611 N, 120.780512 E` as text. I want to be able to click that to open another page leading to http://maps.google.com/maps?q=24.197611,120.780512

Since the coordinates are inside brackets (**14.495569 N, 9.139927 E**), I used something like this:

```
    $("div").html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/\((.+?)\)/g, "<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=#$1'>$1</a>");
});
```

But the link also gets the bold part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use the following regex to match the coordinates in the format that you use:

```
\((<b>)?(\d+\.\d+ [NEWS], \d+\.\d+) [NEWS](<\/b>)?\)
```

In this case you have three capturing groups. Capturing group #2 matches the coordinates in the format Google Maps hyperlink uses.

Here is how it would work with the code that you provided:

```
$("div").html(function(i, html) {
return html.replace(/\((<b>)?(\d+\.\d+ [NEWS], \d+\.\d+) [NEWS](<\/b>)?\)/g, "<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=#$2'>$2</a>");
});
```

Comment: Cardinal directions are no problem,

`http://maps.google.com/maps?q=24.197611 N, 120.780512 E`

Will also work, but your solutions doesn't work if bold tags are used

Comment: @Kharg I updated the answer. Now it should work for both `(<b>14.495569 N, 9.139927 E</b>)` and `(14.495569 N, 9.139927 E)`. I highly recommend using http://www.regexr.com/ for creating and testing regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

So, at last I used something like this whick works

```
    function myFunction() {
    $("div").each(function(i, html) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.html($this.html().replace(/((\d+\.\d+) [N], (\d+\.\d+) [E])/g, "<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>"));
        });
  }
  $(document).ready(myFunction);
  setTimeout(myFunction, 2000);
```

Even if it seems to slowdown things